# Problems with belongs_to condition in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, pg

I'm making personal money management app. There I have 2 models: `Account` and `Transaction`.
`Transaction` has `belongs_to :account` and `Account` has `has_many :transactions`.

When I had `account_id` column in db (postgres) everything worked fine. But I have to rename `account_id` to `from_account_id` and add another column `to_account_id`. So that I can add a spending from `Account` and income to `Account`. Also it's necessary for transfers between accounts (where `from_account_id` and `to_account_id` both will have some values).

So, I've renamed fields `:account_id` in my views to `:from_account_id` and add `:to_account_id` field. But, when I rename `account_id` to `from_account_id` in db, I've got this error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PagesController#index

PG::Error: ERROR:  column transactions.account_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...s".* FROM "transactions" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "transacti...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON
  "transactions"."account_id" = "accounts"."id" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = 17 ORDER BY
  transactions.date DESC
```

My `Pages#index` controller is:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      @accounts = current_user.accounts.all
      @transaction = current_user.transactions.build
      @transactions = current_user.transactions.all
      @categories = current_user.categories.all
    end
  end

end
```

I think Rails is trying to find `account_id` column in `transactions` table, because `Transaction` `belongs_to :account`. But I need both columns for `:account` `to` and `from`, as you see. So, maybe I need to change this `belongs_to` condition in `Transaction` model, but I don't know how.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define two `belong_to` relations in your `Transaction` class, one for each column in your table `transactions`:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :from_account, :class_name => 'Account', :foreign_key => 'from_account_id'
  belongs_to :to_account, :class_name => 'Account', :foreign_key => 'to_account_id'

  # ...
end
```

See options in [Rails Relation Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to rename the `has_many` relation in `Account` model. Something like below will work:

`has_many :transactions, :foreign_key => "from_account_id"`